# Sending data from windows service to WCF - MaxArrayLength Error

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-services

I've had a problem sending data from a local service to a web service for a while now, and I've tried many articles, but they all dont seem to help...
When I run the app I get the following error:
"The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader."

Here is my web.config for the wcf service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IOnlineSyncService" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000" maxBufferPoolSize="50000000" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="500000000" maxStringContentLength="500000000" maxArrayLength="500000000" maxBytesPerRead="500000000" maxNameTableCharCount="500000000" />
      <security mode="None"/>
     </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
     <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
     </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
   <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

My App.config on my Windows Service is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
   <sources>
    <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
     <listeners>
      <add name="FileLog"/>
     </listeners>
    </source>
   </sources>
   <switches>
    <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
   </switches>
   <sharedListeners>
    <add name="FileLog" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
   </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IOnlineSyncService" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="50000000" maxBufferPoolSize="50000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="50000000" maxArrayLength="50000000" maxBytesPerRead="50000000" maxNameTableCharCount="50000000" />
      <security mode="None">
       <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
       <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
     </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:65093/OnlineSyncService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IOnlineSyncService" contract="MyApp.OnlineSyncService.IOnlineSyncService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IOnlineSyncService" />
   </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

I call it from a windows app (MySyncService.Upload_Cust_Data(fileContents, BranchID, MyFile.Name))
filecontents is defined as a Byte()

I'm defining the MaxArrayLength property on both files, but it still gives me the same error.
I am up in arms with this one :(

Answer (score 0):

have you tried remove the binding name in the wcf service, and set it to blank?
So the binding overrides the default binding.

Since you don't specify an endpoint I assume that the wcf service use default binding config.